# How to add a new language - Magento 2.0.1

Tags: magento2, localisation, language-package

I am trying to create a new store view for the Tamil Language, but the language does not get listed while choosing the language from admin.

**short description of what I have done**

1) I have successfully created Tamil Store View. Please refer the screenshot for your easy reference.

[image: tamil store view]

2) Next, I am trying to add Tamil Language Package

**2.1 collect phrases**

create the folder `/var/www/html/magento2/app/i18n/tamil/tn_tn/`

after that run the below command and get a success message

```
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "/var/www/html/magento2/app/i18n/tamil/tn_tn/dictionary.csv" -m "/var/www/html/magento2/"
```

**2.2 composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "tamil/tn"
    ,"type": "magento2-language"
    ,"description": "Tamil language"
    ,"authors": [{
    "name": "Bilal Usean",
    "email": "yyyyyy@yyyyy.yyy",
    "role": "Developer"
    }]  
    ,"extra": {"map": [["*", "tamil/tn_tn"]]}
}
```

**2.3 language.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<language xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd'>
    <code>tn_TN</code>
    <vendor>tamil</vendor>
    <package>tn_tn</package>
</language>
```

**2.4 registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
   'tamil_tn_tn',
   __DIR__
);
```

**2.5 Translate**

dictionary.csv contains 8000+ rows of phrases for the sample I have taken one (**open in gedit**)

```
"We found other products you might like!","We found other products you might like!",module,Magento_Catalog
```

tn_TN.csv I have translated above particular line (contains one row)(**open in gedit**)

```
"We found other products you might like!","நீங்கள் விரும்பக்கூடிய மற்ற பொருட்கள் காணப்படும் !",module,Magento_Catalog
```

**2.6 Language pack**

run the below command for creating the language pack and get a success message `Successfully saved tn_TN language package`.

```
php bin/magento i18n:pack -d app/i18n/tamil/tn_tn/tn_TN.csv tn_tn tn_TN
```

It will create directory (tn_tn pack)

```
<magento-root>/tn_tn/vendor/magento/module-catalog/i18n/tn_TN.csv
```

someone noted it, collect phrases and lang pack commands are different from the official doc, please refer this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116775/collect-phrases-and-lang-pack-command-line-different-from-official-doc-magento) for why am I using like this way.

**Overall structure of my language package**

[image]

After that clear cache, run setup:upgrade, indexer:reindex but I can't found my Tamil language pack in newly created **Tamil store view** locale options.

[image: easy for your reference]

I would like to mention one more, I have researched about existing lang pack `/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/language-de_de` (composer.json, language.xml, registration.php) but unable to find the exact name of the locale like listed in admin(German (Germany)). So I confused any step I missed to create locale.

**why Tamil language package does not get installed?**

Comment: What do you mean by roadmap ?

Comment: steps to achieve

Comment: Which language ?

Comment: Tamil language  @Arunendra

Comment: Are you able to do it ? If yes then please share the process

Answer (score 5):

### Step 1: collect the phrases

First, you need to find out the phrases that you need to translate.

You can do so by running:

```
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "/path/to/magento2/app/i18n/vendor/lg_lg/dictionary.csv"
```

Note that `vendor` is the same as when you develop module and `lg_lg` is the lang code of your language.

### Step 2: create the `composer.json` file

Go to your `app/i18n/vendor/lg_lg` folder and create the `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "vendor/lg"
    ,"type": "magento2-language"
    ,"description": "Tamil language"
    ,"authors": [{
        "name": "Bilal Usean",
        "email": "bla@bla.com",
        "role": "Developer"
    }]  
    ,"extra": {"map": [["*", "vendor/lg_lg"]]}
}
```

### Step 3: create the `language.xml` file

Still in your `app/i18n/vendor/lg_lg` folder you need to create a `language.xml` file:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<language xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd'>
    <code>lg_LG</code>
    <vendor>vendor</vendor>
    <package>lg_lg</package>
</language>
```

### Step 4: create the `registration.php` file

Still in the same folder, you need to create a `registration.php` file:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
   'vendor_lg_lg',
   __DIR__
);
```

### Step 5: translate

Still in your folder, you can start writing your translations in a `lg_lg.csv` file based on the dictionary you retrieved in step 1. You can use the offical guide to follow the translation guidelines: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-dict-trans

### Step 6: create the language pack

Run the following command:

```
php bin/magento i18n:pack app/i18n/vendor/lg_lg/lg_lg.csv lg_Lg lg_LG
```

### Important note

For this to work, your .csv file name must exactly match the locale, including the characters' case.

Official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-example2

Comment: I have done what you listed but new language not listed in new store view, anything did I miss?

Comment: Did you try to remove `var/generation`, `var/cache` and `var/di` ?

Comment: Yes, it is default action for me :-)  whatever I have changed first I remove var/*. I have updated my question

Comment: if you have a moments review this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116650/setup-upgrade-not-working-for-language-package-magento-2

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 2):

in  **Tamil** 
you must add iso code and international code for Tamil
**ta_IN** (Tamil- **ta** / INDIA - **IN**)
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_country_codes.asp

and you need to add this code in  `vendor/magento/framework/Locale/config.php`
directory
[image]

then you install by using command "**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f ta_IN**"

hope it will work

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't add new language in the General **locale option**

The reason is because magento uses  php **intl**  library to populate the select box

see the following file

```
vendor/magento/framework/Locale/TranslatedLists.php
```

> method _getOptionLocales()

Comment: i think so, How can we customize or add new local language..

Comment: @matinict you can utilize existing unused one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step-by-step guide to create a language package.

Run [`i18n:collect-phrases`](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-dict-dict) to collect all phrases to be translated:

An example:

```
bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "<path to Magento>/app/i18n/df/ru_ru/dictionary.csv" -m
```

**Step 2**

Create a Magento 2 extension for the language package.

**Step 2.1**

Create a **composer.json** file.
An example from the core:

```
magento/magento2/blob/2.0.0/app/i18n/magento/de_de/composer.json

{
    "name": "magento/language-de_de",
    "description": "German (Germany) language",
    "version": "100.0.2",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-language",
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

My **composer.json**:

```
{
    "name": "dfl/ru"
    ,"type": "magento2-language"
    ,"description": "Russian language"
    ,"homepage": "https://mage2.pro"
    ,"license": "proprietary"
    ,"authors": [{
        "name": "Dmitry Fedyuk",
        "email": "admin@mage2.pro",
        "homepage": "https://mage2.pro/users/dmitry_fedyuk",
        "role": "Developer"
    }]  
    ,"extra": {"map": [["*", "df/ru_ru"]]}
}
```

**Step 2.2**

Create a **language.xml** file.

An example from the core:

**magento/magento2/blob/2.0.0/app/i18n/magento/de_de/language.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
    <code>de_DE</code>
    <vendor>magento</vendor>
    <package>de_de</package>
</language>
```

My **language.xml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<language xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd'>
    <code>ru_RU</code>
    <vendor>df</vendor>
    <package>ru_ru</package>
</language>
```

**Step 2.3**

Create a **registration.php** file.

An example from the core:

**magento/magento2/blob/2.0.0/app/i18n/magento/de_de/registration.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
    'magento_de_de',
    __DIR__
);
?>
```

I use an [universal `registration.php`66](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/131).

**Step 3**

[Install the extension](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/25)

**Step 4**

Do the actual translation and keep your extension updated.
See other localization topics: https://mage2.pro/tags/localization

[Source.](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/270)

Comment: thanks, already I had tried this link but it will not listed created language in store view.

Comment: did you guess anything I miss? I have updated my question

Comment: Have you run setup and cleared the cache ?

Comment: yes I did but the problem remains, How to check language extension status? like (config.php or any command line)

Answer (score 0):

**Step1:** Create the file **composer.json** like this

```
{
   "name": "tamil/tn_tn",
   "description": "Tamil language",
   "authors": [{
     "name": "Bilal Usean",
     "email": "xxxxxxx@xxxx.xxx",
     "role": "Developer"
   }],
   "require": {
     "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
   },
   "type": "magento2-language",
   "autoload": {
     "files": [
       "registration.php"
     ]
   }
   ,"extra": {"map": "*", "tamil/tn_tn"}
 }
```

**Step2:** Create the file **language.xml** like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
   <code>tn_TN</code>
   <vendor>tamil</vendor>
   <package>tn_tn</package>
 </language>
```

**Step3:** Create the file **registration.php** like this

```
<?php
 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
     \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
     'tamil_tn_tn',
     __DIR__
 );
```

**Step4:** Now place the translated file **tn_TN.csv** in the **/app/i18n/tamil/tn_tn** directory

Comment: still the problem remains..... not listed in newly created store view, anything need to be configured from backend?

Comment: syntax: you missed comma (,) in author

Comment: Fixed and added (,) ... you must install it after creating, did you?

Comment: install mean run setup:upgrade

Comment: @BilalUsean: Yes, run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` ... after that open `/app/etc/config.php` and check value of `tamil_tn_tn` be **1**

Comment: if you have a moments review this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116650/setup-upgrade-not-working-for-language-package-magento-2