# setup upgrade not list the language package extension - Magento 2.0.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, store-view, language

I am trying to create new language store view. after creating language extension, then I have cleared cache

1) When I run **setup:upgrade** it is not listed my language extension lang_lg_lg

2) In config.php also not contain my lang extension as active (**1**).

3) when I run this **bin/magento info:language:list** it will not list my language.

4) **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy  lg_LG** not succeed

===============================================================

**Short Description of what I have done**

tree folder structure of language extension

[image: tree structure of lang pack]

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "lang/lg"
    ,"type": "magento2-language"
    ,"description": "Tamil language"
    ,"authors": [{
    "name": "Bilal Usean",
    "email": "yyyyy@yyy.yyy",
    "role": "Developer"
    }]  
    ,"extra": {"map": [["*", "lang/lg_lg"]]}
}
```

**language.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<language xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd'>
    <code>lg_LG</code>
    <vendor>lang</vendor>
    <package>lg_lg</package>
</language>
```

**registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
   'lang_lg_lg',
   __DIR__
);
```

**lg_LG.csv** (copy all values from dictionary.csv then edit the one row of second coloumn) (that row in gedit it seems like)

```
"We found other products you might like!","நீங்கள் விரும்பக்கூடிய மற்ற பொருட்கள் காணப்படும் !",module,Magento_Catalog
```

**dictionary.csv** contains 8000+ rows of phrases for sample I have take one

```
"We found other products you might like!","We found other products you might like!",module,Magento_Catalog
```

**note:** I am using libre office to edit csv

if anyone point out what did I wrong?

Comment: did you find the answer for this one? I m stumbling on this one as well. On production server, it works well, the language is in the list. But when I copied filesystem and sql on staging, when i go through php bin/magento info:language:list, one of the languages does not show. I reinstall it via php bin/magento i18n:pack, and static deploy, didnt work too