# collect phrases and lang pack command line different from official doc - Magento 2.0.1

Tags: magento2, store-view, language

I use magento version 2.0.1, I am trying to add new language package, I have followed the instruction from [official doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-pack), that commands are not working

command syntax mentioned in official doc

```
magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "/var/www/html/magento2/xx_YY.csv" -m

magento i18n:pack [-m|--mode={merge|replace}] [-d|--allow-duplicates] <source> <locale>
```

example mentioned in official doc

```
magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "/var/www/html/magento2/xx_YY.csv" -m

magento i18n:pack /var/www/html/magento2/xx_YY.csv -d xx_YY
```

when I run  this command I got error **Not enough arguments.** and give suggestion like

```
i18n:collect-phrases [-o|--output="..."] [-m|--magento] directory


i18n:pack [-m|--mode="..."] [-d|--allow-duplicates] source pack locale
```

I have tried this

**Collect Phrases**

```
bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "/var/www/html/magento2/app/i18n/test/te_te/te_TE.csv" -m "/var/www/html/magento2/"
```

I got success message like this

```
Dictionary successfully processed.
```

**Language Pack**

```
bin/magento i18n:pack -d app/i18n/test/te_te/te_TE.csv te_te te_TE
```

I got success message like this

```
Successfully saved te_TE language package.
```

but my new language not listed in new store view in admin so I am get confused whether the command is correct or not.

pub/static/* folder contains only en_US

Thanks.

Comment: For one, you should upgrade your install to the latest version. 2.0.1 is old, and means you don't have a very important security fix (released in 2.0.6). Upgrading 2.x is very fast and easy.

Comment: I have checked with 2.0.5 but I got same command problem what I get 2.0.1

Comment: This is my fault. I updated the documentation a while back without understanding that the syntax will be available in 2.1. Right now I cannot give you an ETA of when I can update it. Meanwhile, try the command help. You're correct about the syntax being wrong. I wish I had a better answer.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146735/magento-2-how-to-install-new-language-pack

Answer (score -1):

**run php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy te_TE en_US**

or to be sure run this :

*

```
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy te_TE en_US
redis-cli FLUSHALL
php -f bin/magento cache:clean
php -f bin/magento cache:flush
php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

*