# Magento 2 : How to install new language pack

Tags: magento2, localisation, locale, language-package

I am working on a Magento-2 website which is based on German language.

How to install and use new language package for German language in  Magento2.

Which package is best for German language?

Any one have an idea about it. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have done by just using below command for it

```
composer require splendidinternet/mage2-locale-de-de

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE
```

**Note :** commands need to be run from your magento root.

**More info :** [Magento 2 German LocalePack de_DE](https://github.com/splendidinternet/Magento2_German_LocalePack_de_DE)

It's works for me.

Comment: You can add your extra translation for German language to app/i18n/splendid/de_DE/de_DE.csv.

Comment: Have you installed by command line?

Comment: Have you setup upgrade or deployed static content? And current store language must be German. Also deploy content with pass language like php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_Us de_DE.

Comment: As per my suggestion, You need to uninstall module from vendor and install it by manually.

Answer (score 4):

[Package link](https://github.com/splendidinternet/Magento2_German_LocalePack_de_DE)

To install it:

1. extract and copy into `/app/i18n/splendid/de_DE/`
2. Remove `pub/static/*`
3. Run Command using CLI:

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   ```
4. Remove `var/*`
5. Run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to Magento's community engineering projects and there are also translation repositories:

https://github.com/magento-l10n

From there you can check the name of the locale. For example *language-es_ES*

Then you can run this:

```
composer require community-engineering/language-es_ES
bin/magento cache:clean
```

And of course also change the locale in Magento admin settings.

Here is an article from where I found this solution:

https://fooman.com/blog/language-packs-for-magento-2.html

Answer (score -1):

I need some help to setup chinese language on my magento 2.4 (VPS hosting)
I want to use composer method  like mentionned here: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-chinese-language-pack
But i dont know in which folder of my server i should install the language pack and execute first step : ```
composer require mageplaza/magento-2-chinese-language-pack:dev-master mageplaza/module-smtp

```
Is it to  /var/www/html/magento/app ( i dont have i18n file under app)
under app i have code, design, etc, htaccess, autoload.php, boostrap.pho
or directly to root, under root i have composer-setup.php,default.confback,...
Please check the screen shot of my server ( file directory) and screen shot when i connect to server using SSH (putty)
Thanks
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2][![enter image description here][3]][3][![enter image description here][4]][4][![enter image description here][5]][5][![enter image description here][6]][6][![enter image description here][7]][7][![enter image description here][8]][8]
[![enter image description here][9]][9][![enter image description here][10]][10][![enter image description here][11]][11][![enter image description here][12]][12]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHYHO.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A093q.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfcFc.jpg
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRPFF.jpg
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIaMF.jpg
  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz0hO.jpg
  [7]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOcSV.jpg
  [8]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3bYd.jpg
  [9]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBiVJ.jpg
  [10]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai8UO.jpg
  [11]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCgqo.jpg
  [12]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQBd1.jpg
```