# How to change default language to French

Tags: localisation, language, magento-2.1.7

I am working with **Magento 2.1.7** and I want to set up a website that will completely display in French.

I did install the community version, 2.1.7 of it and it works well.

But I am trying to change the default language to **French** and it's a bit hard to do (Two weeks later, It is still not done).

I did change the language to French in Store `configuration > General` :

- Country Options
- Locale Options
- Site Information

But everything is still in **English**.

I found a lot of tutorials on that issue. But they all talk about previous versions of Magento 2.x. This one (the 2.1.7) seems a bit different.

Can anybody help me find out How to Change The Default Language To French or another language?

Comment: You want to change backend or frontend language ?

Comment: I want to change both of them : Front and Back end.

Comment: First you have to install language pack for magento2 ,and for admin side you can set from edit user

Comment: I have try a lot of times to install the language first. But when I copy the french package's key from magento I can see no place to put in on the site. In fact the rutorials that I have seen show a different interface. So that I don't know where to go to install the language package.

Comment: So can you tell me must I install the package ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For translate you have to install language pack.
For that download language pack and put at magentoroot/app/i18n/vendor/fr_fr
ref: [Magento 2 : How to install new language pack](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146735/magento-2-how-to-install-new-language-pack)

Change language of frontend : **Store > Configuration > General > Locale Options**

Change language of backend : **System > All Users > Click Any User and change Interface Locale**

Then fire below commands:

- `php bin/magento cache:flush`
- `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR`
- `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: After a very long time it did work. Wouah! Such a very hard work. But finally. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do :

- `composer require mageplaza/magento-2-french-language-pack`
- `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR`
- `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
- `php bin/magento cache:clean`
- `php bin/magento cache:flush`

et Voila!
Source: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-french-language-pack

Comment: But it generates an error :

Comment: Package "mageplaza/magento-2-french-language-pack" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://repo.magento.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo fa
  iled: H¶te inconnu.
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: H¶te inconnu.

Comment: This happens when I type the line "composer update mageplaza/magento-2-french-language-pack"

Comment: I do it on command line. A username and password are been asked to me. I feel them with my admin user and password. Then that error displays...

Comment: please see my updated answer