# How to setup a new language in magento2?

Tags: magento2, language

I found this website (https://crowdin.com/project/magento-2) and the respective instructions (http://www.vanderboon.net/wiki/Install_Magento_Crowdin_Translation). Unfortunatly even after doing everything explained I don't get the translations. I also changed the localization in the configuration.

I should had that I am not using the default luma theme but one that I bought.

How can I setup a new language in magento2?

Comment: refer below link you got idea about how to add new language pack but it did not work for me, may be it is work for you or you can improve further :-) http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116515/how-to-add-a-new-language-magento-2-0-1  if it is work please mention in comment :-)