# Magento2: Install language package

Tags: magento-2.1, language, language-package

Which is the right procedure to install a new language in Magento2?

I downloaded the Italian language package from the site Crowdin https://crowdin.com/project/magento-2/it

What I get is a zip whose structure is

```
app/
dev/
lib/
```

I unzipped the archive in my Magento2 root installation and tried to set Italian locale from my backend but nothing happens in the frontend.

Which is the right way do install a new language?

Answer (score 0):

See this
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html

and also this

[How to add a new language - Magento 2.0.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116515/how-to-add-a-new-language-magento-2-0-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the official GitHub page, in which you'll find all the information about how to install the language pack, using different methods: using Composer or Manual installation.

The page is here: https://github.com/Magento2Translations/language_it_it

If you are looking for a different language, see this list: https://github.com/Magento2Translations